# java List refence index

Tags: java, list, reference

Exam question:
Define generic class Table, having in mind that class based on java.utils.List, define class attribute(s). Then define constructor Table(int rows, int columns) that creates and fills table with 'null'. After that define two methods:

```
List<E> getRow(int row) returns list of elements in row;
List<E> gerColumn(int column) returns list of elements in columns
```

Note: it should be possible modify inicial table with a returned value.

My implementation:

```
public class Table<E> {

    private List<List<E>> table;

    public Table(int r, int c) {
        this.table=new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i=0; i<r; i++){
            table.add(new ArrayList<>());
            for (int j=0; j<c; j++){
                table.get(i).add(null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now what i need is two methods:
List getRow(int i) which returns a row with number i;
List getColumn(int j) which returns a column with number j;

These methods should return references, or with example:

```
//rows() and columns() methods are returning int number
//of rows and colums of this table, respectively

Table<String> t=new Table<>(2, 2);

for (int i=0; i<t.rows(); i++){    
    System.out.println(t.getRow(i));
}

System.out.println();

t.getRow(0).set(1,"Lorem ipsum");

for (int i=0; i<t.rows(); i++){    
    System.out.println(t.getRow(i));
}
```

Should print:

```
[null, null]
[null, null]

[null, Lorem ipsum]
[null, null]
```

-> initial table 't' have changed.

So, in case of getRow() is pretty easy:

```
public List<E> getRow(int i) {
    return this.table.get(i);
}
```

But I can't do same with getColumn.
What I have now, returns a row but it doesn't make reference to this table,
only to object at position:

```
public List<E> getColumn(int j) {
    List<E> temp=new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i=0; i<this.rows(); i++){
        temp.add(this.table.get(i).get(j));
    }
    return temp;
}
```

I understand why it's happening, but I really don't know how to implements it as it asked.
 
I'm now not sure that class attributes and constructor done for such funcionality.

Comment: A reference to a 2-dimensional array element _location_ is a pair of indices. If you want to pass such references around, you'll have to use another object capable of holding that, and then you might need some methods for getting at the object reference actually stored there, or to replace it. - I wonder whether you really need this.

Comment: @laune im not sure i understood what you said but generally all i need in this exercise is class Table, attributes, constructor and two methods getRow(), getColumn

Comment: Would be a good idea represent a row element (List<E>) as a different class for example MyRow, and inside it put a method getColumn(int cIndex). It has molt sense do that because as a @laune said, a two dimensional structure must be treated as is. Another point is that, in your example, the element column can't be a List<E> element, but E element.
Hope this help

Comment: This is homework?  It basically cannot be done the way you are asking, at least not with standard implementations of List like `ArrayList`.  If you are allowed to define your own type of list, then the list could work some magic.

Comment: @markspace it's an exam question, i've updated thread on top

Comment: 'Based on List` doesn't say to me that you can't make your own list type, as cocsackie did below.  I think that's basically the solution.  Although the directions you posted are pretty vague (at least as translated into English).

Comment: @markspace i've forgot statement of the question a little, but a sense is still same. Anyway if it isnt possible this way, next week there will be an exam review and ill ask a teacher how it suppose to be done

Comment: @ВолодимирКельбель It would be interesting to learn how this was meant to be done! Getting a row so that you can change the original table is no problem: you return one of the List objects representing the rows. But you can't do that with a column, running across all rows. You can call anything on an E object of row or column and it'll affect the original E in the table, but what if it (String!) is immutable? - My guess is that your solution would have been accepted as OK. But the wording of the exam question is lousy.

Answer (score 0):

There might exist a better solution to this problem, but the simplest one to describe is:

List is an interface, why don't you implement a List that uses your List of Lists? An inner class would look like this:

```
public class ColumnList extends AbstractList<E> {
    private Integer column;

    public ColumnList(Integer column) {
        this.column = column;
    }

    @Override
    public E get(int index) {
        return table.get(index).get(column);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return table.size();
    }

    @Override
    public E set(int index, E element) {
        return table.get(index).set(column, element);
    }
}
```

Then the method `getRow` would look like this:

```
public List<E> getColumn(int index) {
    return new ColumnList(index);
}
```

Where [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html) states:

> To implement an unmodifiable list, the programmer needs only to extend this class and provide implementations for the get(int) and size() methods.
>
> To implement a modifiable list, the programmer must additionally override the set(int, E) method (which otherwise throws an UnsupportedOperationException).
>
> If the list is variable-size the programmer must additionally override the add(int, E) and remove(int) methods.

Something of importance:
I would recommend implementing list for rows as well, because adding to `ArrayList` is not forbidden.

Instead of using List of Lists you could use an array instead.

Comment: I understand your solution, but it is asked all to be done in class Table without any Overriding of List interface. Btw i was thinking about make two different attributes for rows and column over single attribute table, but im not sure how to make it all connected

Comment: @cocsakie  it's an exam question, one of many and single that had some complexity, i've updated thread on top

Answer (score 0):

This is how I think could work for you,

```
public class Table<E> {

    private List<Row<E>> table;

    public Table(int r, int c) {
        this.table = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
            table.add(new Row<>(new ArrayList<>()));
            for (int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
                table.get(i).add(null);
            }
        }
    }

    public int rows() {
        return table.size();
    }

    public List<Row<E>> getTable() {
        return table;
    }

    public void setTable(List<Row<E>> table) {
        this.table = table;
    }

    public Row<E> getRow(int rowIndex) {
        if(rowIndex >= 0 && rowIndex < table.size())
            return table.get(rowIndex);
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Table{" + "table=" + table + '}';
    }        
}
```

> Blockquote

```
public class Row<E> {

List<E> columnList;

public Row() {
}

public Row(List<E> columnList) {
    this.columnList = columnList;
}

public void add(E colValue) {
    columnList.add(colValue);
}

public void set(int cIndex, E cValue) {
    columnList.set(cIndex, cValue);
}

public E getColumn(int colIndex) {
    if(colIndex >= 0 && colIndex < columnList.size())
        return columnList.get(colIndex);
    throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
}

public int columns() {
    return columnList.size();
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Row{" + "columnList=" + columnList + '}';
  }
}
```

> Blockquote

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Table<String> t = new Table<>(2, 2);

    for (int i = 0; i < t.rows(); i++) {
        System.out.println(t.getRow(i));
    }

    System.out.println();

    t.getRow(0).set(1, "Lorem ipsum");

    for (int i = 0; i < t.rows(); i++) {
        System.out.println(t.getRow(i));
    }
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: Understand your solution and fully agree, but that was exam question of today to do with a pen.  I've updated thread on top